# Why arent my buttons changing height but only with with the Auto property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

So I have this test application with a few buttons, an image etc.
And when I move the window side to side, the controls gets squished together.. That's good.
Now if I move up and down.. Especially up, they don't get *thinner* I guess you would call it. Why is that? I've tried setting the height proeprty to auto. it doesnt do anything. Same goes for the Image, it's not shrinking if I go up and down only side to side.
[GIF Showing what happens](https://i.imgur.com/Bldz6Nn.gifv)

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions >
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="0"
          Background="Gray">


        <StackPanel Height="auto">
            <TextBlock Text="Image Preview"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       Height="25"
                       Width="auto"/>

            <Image Source="{Binding ProcessImage.PreviewImage}"
                       Height="auto"
                   Width="auto"
                       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant"
                       Stretch="Uniform"/>


            <ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding ProcessImage.SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Height="auto"
                      Width="auto"
                      VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="North east"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="North west"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="South east"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="South west"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Center"/>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <Button Content="Preview"
                    Width="auto"
                    Height="30"
                    Command="{Binding PreviewImageCommand}"/>

            <Button Width="auto"
                    Height="30"
                    Content="Directory"
                    Command="{Binding AddDirectoryCommand}"/>

            <TextBox Width="auto"
                     Height="auto"
                     Text="{Binding ProcessImage.Directory, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

            <Button Width="auto"
                    Height="30"
                    Content="Watermark"
                    Command="{Binding AddWatermarkDirectoryCommand}"/>

            <TextBox Width="auto"
                     Height="auto"
                     Text="{Binding ProcessImage.WatermarkImage}"/>

            <Button Width="auto"
                    Height="30"
                    Content="Process"
                    Command="{Binding ProcessCommand}"
                    Margin="0,15,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That would throw an error because the string cannot be converted to `Length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is that?

Because the grid that contains your image has two rows defined to take up half of the grid's height each. And the grid rows actually *get thinner* as seen in the gif.

Your problem's the `StackPanel` that's wrapped around the image. It won't shrink the image inside, so better put the image directly into the grid.

Comment: Ahhh! That makes sense!